# ERROR IN ANDROID STUDIO:cannot resolve symbol R

Tags: android-studio

I tried everything possible
cleaned the project,rebuild it,went to file-->invalidate caches/restart ,did sync project with gradles,change the sdk version but nothing is working out.
It even shows this:
AAPT2 error: check logs for details

On even searching the internet I couldn't find any apt solutions.

Need help

Comment: Android studio usually cannot resolve the symbol R when the android resource linking has failed. If you run a full build, do you get an AAPT/AAPT2 error before the javac/kotlinc failure?

Answer (score 0):

@Izabela Orlowska yes this error does come.